# Usando o resultado de uma função em outra

Tags: javascript

```
var request = require('request');
request.get('https://r2d2-secret-pass.herokuapp.com/validate', function(err, resp, body){
  console.log(body);
});

function CheckPassword(password){
  var psw = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]\w{1,6}$/;
  if (password.value.match(psw)){
    alert('Senha válida, redirecionando ..');
    document.location.assign(body);
    return false;
  }
  else{
    alert('Senha inválida. Tente novamente.');
    return true;
  }
}
```

Sou iniciante no JavaScript e preciso usar o 'body' da primeira função no 'document.location.assign' da segunda, alguma dica de como fazer ?

Comment: Tente o seguinte: antes do request, coloque `var body;`.... e dentro do request coloque `body = body;`

Comment: @Sam me retorna undefined, mesmo dentro do 'body' tenho um link pra um vídeo do youtube

Comment: O request é assíncrono (AJAX). Logo a variável body ainda não existe na função.

Answer (score 0):

Tens duas opções:

- `a)` ou chamas o `request.get()` dentro de `CheckPassword`
- `b)`ou guardas o url/body de `request.get()` e consomes dentro de `CheckPassword`

### Opção a)

```js
var request = require('request');

function CheckPassword(password) {
  var psw = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]\w{1,6}$/;
  if (password.value.match(psw)) {
    alert('Senha válida, redirecionando ..');

    request.get('https://r2d2-secret-pass.herokuapp.com/validate', function(err, resp, body) {
      if (!err) document.location.assign(body);
    });
    return false;
  } else {
    alert('Senha inválida. Tente novamente.');
    return true;
  }
}
```

### Opção b)

```js
var request = require('request');
let url = '';
request.get('https://r2d2-secret-pass.herokuapp.com/validate', function(err, resp, body) {
  url = body;
});

function CheckPassword(password) {
  var psw = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]\w{1,6}$/;
  if (password.value.match(psw)) {
    alert('Senha válida, redirecionando ..');
    document.location.assign(url);
    return false;
  } else {
    alert('Senha inválida. Tente novamente.');
    return true;
  }
}
```